how to style DatePicker with MUI? in typescript
im new to use MUI and DatePicker
im trying to change colors of selected dates in the code but nothing works with me
here is my code:
<DatePicker
  slotProps={{
    textField: {
      size: isDesktop ? "medium" : "small",
      variant: "standard",
    },
  }}
  sx={{
    flex: 1,
    fontSize: ".875rem !important",
    "& input::placeholder": {
      fontSize: ".875rem !important",
    },
    ".MuiOutlinedInput-root": {
      fontSize: ".875rem !important",
    },
    "& .MuiPickersDay-root": {
      color: "white",
      "&:hover": {
        backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 128, 255, 0.2)",
        color: "blue",
      },
      "&.Mui-selected": {
        backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 128, 255, 0.3) !important",
        color: "white !important",
        "&:hover": {
          backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 128, 255, 0.4) !important",
        },
      },
    },
  }}
  value={startShowDate}
  format="dd/MM/yyyy"
  onChange={(newValue) => startDateHandle(newValue)}
/>
<DatePicker
  slotProps={{
    textField: {
      size: isDesktop ? "medium" : "small",
      variant: "standard",
    },
  }}
  sx={{
    flex: 1,
    fontSize: ".875rem !important",
    "& input::placeholder": {
      fontSize: ".875rem !important",
    },
    ".MuiOutlinedInput-root": {
      fontSize: ".875rem !important",
    },
    "& .MuiPickersDay-root": {
      color: "white",
      "&:hover": {
        backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 128, 255, 0.2)",
        color: "blue",
      },
      "&.Mui-selected": {
        backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 128, 255, 0.3) !important",
        color: "red !important",
        "&:hover": {
          backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 128, 255, 0.4) !important",
        },
      },
    },
  }}
  value={endShowDate}
  format="dd/MM/yyyy"
  onChange={(newValue) => endDateHandle(newValue)}
/>

noting that ive read the documentations and tried Props but still not working with me
so the idea is to change the color of the selected days
any help would be highly appreciated!

Admittedly the docs are pretty sparse on this, but you want to target the "paper" slots – and since you're handling both desktop/mobile, you'll probably want to do this for both desktopPaper and mobilePaper:
<DatePicker
  slotProps={{
    textField: {
      size: "medium",
      variant: "standard",
    },
    desktopPaper: {
      sx: {
        "& .MuiDateCalendar-root": {
          backgroundColor: "white",
          "& [class$='MuiPickersDay-root'].Mui-selected": {
            backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 128, 255, 0.3) !important",
            color: "white",
          },
        },
      },
    },
  }}
  sx={{}}
  value={startShowDate}
  format="dd/MM/yyyy"
  onChange={(newValue) => startDateHandle(newValue)}
/>

You may also have some luck doing this directly in your theme:
const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiDatePicker: {
      defaultProps: {
        displayWeekNumber: true,
      },
    },
    MuiDateCalendar: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          backgroundColor: "#f0f0f0",
        },
      },
    },
  },
});

// ...

<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
   <YourApp />
</ThemeProvider>


thank u it works!!
